# How can I share photo or video to someone wall with using facebook app_token , because it is required user acc_token ?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I have a problem here ;

I want to share photo or video on someone's wall with my facebook application token . 
But when I am trying to upload a video or photo to my wall for example , It asks for validate user access token to perform this action .Is it because wall is personal and no one can share a video or photo on someone's wall ? Is there any way to do this with application token ? I am using facebook grahp Api in java

Answer (score 0):

As you say it's down to permissions. User access tokens are required to perform certain actions, otherwise applications could pretty much just spam people all the time. Basically the users access token validates they have granted your app the appropriate permissions for publish_stream

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

There's a small bit about the access tokens at the bottom, but basically your app access_token doesn't know that a particular user has granted certain permissions.